# Grid doesn't show up in printer composer

Tags: coordinates, print-composer, grids-graticules, qgis-2.12

I am trying to get a coordinate grid on my map with the printer composer.
I have tried every example and followed it exactly but for some reason the grid doesn't show up at all. I am working with Qgis 2.12.3

- The CSR of the map and the grid are exactly the same
- Ive hit the green plus for a new grid and clicked draw grid
- Ive changed the interval to 1000 map units (1km by 1km)

Ive looked around everywhere to see what I am missing??
Anyone have any idea why the grid is not showing?

Comment: What is the CRS of the map?